# Configure composer to get data from packagist.org via https

Tags: composer-php, packagist

When building files in an environment that blocks outbound http requests, I get an error like:

`Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%ahash.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date`

Is there some way to instruct composer to use https connection to packagist?

I've experienced the issue with both 1.2.0 and 1.6.5 versions of composer.

Comment: which composer version are you using?

Comment: I meant to include that @ivoba sorry for not doing so. It happens with both 1.2.0 and 1.6.5.

Comment: did you set "secure-http":false in your composer json?

Comment: or set globally: composer config -g secure-http false

Comment: @ivoba It's definitely not set in the composer.json file. How can I check the value from composer global config?

Comment: in linux & OSX it should be in ~/.composer/config.json

Comment: @ivoba that file doesn't exist, so I guess I'm using all defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either force composer to use https by:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Or you could set in your composer.json file:

```
"repositories": [
      {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.org"
      },
      { "packagist": false }
    ]
```

[Source: issue #5656 on composer's github repository.](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5656)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very helpful! There is one idea on that github thread to use `repo.packagist.org` instead of just packagist.org. Any reason not to do that in your answer?